# When is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R^4}$ contained in a $3$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, surfaces

Introduction: Let $S$ be a regular connected surface embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$. We know that $S$ is contained in a plane (a $2$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$) iff every point of $S$ is umbilical and the gaussian curvature is constantly zero.

Question: Let $S$ be a regular connected surface embedded in $\mathbb{R^4}$. Do exist some conditions on the first foundamental form or other "intrinsic" properties of the surface that are equivalent to the statement "$S$ is contained in a $3$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$"?

Observation1: $S$ is contained in a $3$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ iff every tangent plane of $S$ is orthogonal to a fixed non zero vector $a$.

Observation2:
Let $\phi : U \rightarrow S$ be a local chart.  $\phi(U)$ is contained in a $3$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ iff $\langle\phi, a \rangle=0 $, for a fixed non zero vector $a$.

Additional question: Suppose $S$ as in the first question. Is the following implication true?: " if $S$ is not contained in any $3$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$ then there exists a poin $p \in S$ such that for every neighborhood $W$ of $p$, $S\cap W$ is not contained in any $3$-dimensional vector subspace". I'm asking if the property is local or global.

Comment: Clearly the shape operator has to have one dimensional image. I suspect that is necessary and sufficient for a connected surface.